# trying to get french accents in my resume

Tags: languages, cv, resume, french

I wrote my resume in English, but now I need to translate it in French. I can't get the French accent to print properly. Here is a minimal example. It says: 
"J'aime cet été" (I love this summer). You'll notice that the "é" doesn't print:

```
\documentclass[margin,line]{res}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{url}
\oddsidemargin -.5in
\evensidemargin -.5in
\textwidth=6.0in
\itemsep=0in
\parsep=0in
\topmargin=0in
\topskip=0in

\newenvironment{list1}{
  \begin{list}{\ding{113}}{%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{0in}
      \setlength{\parsep}{0in} \setlength{\parskip}{0in}
      \setlength{\topsep}{0in} \setlength{\partopsep}{0in}
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{0.17in}}}{\end{list}}

\newenvironment{list2}{
  \begin{list}{$\bullet$}{%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{0in}
      \setlength{\parsep}{0in} \setlength{\parskip}{0in}
      \setlength{\topsep}{0in} \setlength{\partopsep}{0in}
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{0.2in}}}{\end{list}}


\begin{document}

\name{\LARGE My name} \hfill {\em \today}

\begin{resume}
J'aime cet été!
\end{resume}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can always type `J'aime cet \'et\'e`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short **inputenc** is your friend here.

Pasting from your post I found that adding `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}` fixed it (I had to strip out a couple of bits to do with `res.cls` but I checked that `article` gave the same missing characters.

It's also possible that `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` might be the solution -- I don't trust encodings when text has been cut/pasted repeatedly.  The [inputenc docs](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/inputenc?lang=en) might be worth a read.